# Retain selected file after postback with FileUpload

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, file-upload, updatepanel

I have spent hours on this and read countless threads but not sure what i may be missing to get this to work the way i would like.

I would like to select a file to upload and when the user clicks the button to save the record if there are any validation errors to retain the value of file that was selected to upload.

Heres my markup

```
            <asp:MultiView runat="server" ID="RegisterMultiView">
                <asp:View ID="DefaultView" runat="server">
                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upCountryBrands" runat="server">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                        Select parent
                                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator 
                                            SetFocusOnError="true" 
                                            runat="server" ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" 
                                            ControlToValidate="ddlParent" InitialValue="0" 
                                            ValidationGroup="MainForm" ErrorMessage="Please select" 
                                            Display="Dynamic">Required</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlParent" runat="server" 
                                            OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlParent_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>


                            Select Child 
                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator SetFocusOnError="true" runat="server" ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" 
                                        ControlToValidate="ddlChild" InitialValue="0" 
                                        ValidationGroup="MainForm" ErrorMessage="Please select" 
                                        Display="Dynamic">Required</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlChild" runat="server"  
                                        OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlChild_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>

                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                            Name
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator SetFocusOnError="true" runat="server" ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" 
                                ControlToValidate="txtName" ValidationGroup="MainForm" ErrorMessage="Please enter your name" Display="Dynamic">Required</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" MaxLength="100" />

                                Enter description of your issue
                           <asp:TextBox ID="txtIssue" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" /> <%--This is a Tiny MCE control--%>

                           Image 1
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator SetFocusOnError="true" runat="server" ID="rfv1" ControlToValidate="FileUpload1" ValidationGroup="MainForm" 
                                ErrorMessage="Please select an image." Display="Dynamic">Required</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revFileTypes" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Images only." ControlToValidate="FileUpload1" ValidationExpression=".*\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                                <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" AllowMultiple="false" accept="image/*" ViewStateMode="Enabled" EnableViewState="true" />
                                <asp:Label ID="lblImageOneStatus" runat="server"></asp:Label>

                            Image 2
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator SetFocusOnError="true" runat="server" ID="RequiredFieldValidator9" 
                                ControlToValidate="FileUpload2" ValidationGroup="MainForm" ErrorMessage="Images only" Display="Dynamic">Required</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Images only." ControlToValidate="FileUpload2" ValidationExpression=".*\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                                <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" AllowMultiple="false" class="form-control-file" accept="image/*" />

                    <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" ValidationGroup="MainForm" OnClick="btnSave_Click" OnClientClick="txtIssue.triggerSave(false,true);" />                           
                </asp:View>
                <asp:View ID="SuccessView" runat="server">
                    Thanks
                </asp:View>
            </asp:MultiView>
```

Couple of notes:

1. I have an updatePanel surrounding the dropdown so it looks like theres no postback.
2. I have tried surrounding the FileUpload controls with an UpdatePanel but this made no difference.
3. I have a TonyMCE control, i dont think this would add a spanner into the works but i have left out the associated Javascript so i can provide if required.
4. I have tried adding triggers but again this made no difference so i can only assume i am doing something wrong.

How could i ensure when a file is selected using the FileUpload controls and then press Save it retains the value of the file?

Comment: No, you cannot retain the value of the FileUpload after PostBack.

Comment: @Computer - you "kinda" can preserve if you switch to using ajax. that way you can store selected file, as var file = $('input#FileUpload1[type=file]')[0].files[0], and later you can submit using  new FormData(). On the server side, you can retrieve file from Request.Files[0]